# Nested Loop in JavaScript : Can anyone please explain to why I get this result in this code?

Tags: javascript

I'm  learning Nested Loop in Javascript and I just still don't understand why I get this result.

**Original Code:**

```js
    const list = [['A' , 'B' , 'C', 'D'],
                 ['E' , 'F' , 'G', 'H'],
                 ['I' , 'J' , 'K', 'L'] ]; 
       
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length ; i++){ 
       const row = list[i];
       console.log(`LIST #${i + 1}`);

          for (let j = 0; j < row.length ; j++){
           console.log(row[i]);
         }
       }
```

**Result:**

```
LIST #1 
-------
A
LIST #1 
-------
F
LIST #1 
-------
K
```

Can anyone explain to me ? thanks!

**Edit:**
This is not a typo question, I just don't understand why i got A, F  K (4x in a row) when i tried to use **console.log(row[i]);**

Comment: Because it should be `j` and not `i` in `console.log(row[i]);` …?

Comment: (You did not get _single_ `A`, `F` and `K` here btw., you got each four times in a row. Don’t get fooled by your console _grouping_ multiple identical items that get logged one after the other.)

Comment: Can you please tell us exactly on which point you whish have explanations ?
are you expecting to get multiple lines ? are you expecting to get A, E, I ? are you expecting get show LIST#1, LIST#2 and LIST#3 ?

Comment: `console.log("j: " + j, "i :" + i, row[i], row[j]);`

Comment: @Acuao I just don't understand the part in why I get  A , F , K (4x in a row) when I tried to replace console.log(row[j]); to console.log(row[i]);

Comment: run this explanation code https://jsbin.com/bukiqisici/edit?js,console & let me know if it's ok for you

Answer (score 1):

You printed **row[i]**. But You must print **row[j]**

```js
const list = [['A' , 'B' , 'C', 'D'],
             ['E' , 'F' , 'G', 'H'],
             ['I' , 'J' , 'K', 'L'] ]; 
   
for (let i = 0; i < list.length ; i++){ 
   const row = list[i];
   console.log(`LIST #${i + 1}`);

      for (let j = 0; j < row.length ; j++){
       console.log(row[j]);       // here you must print row[ j ] for right answer
     }
   }
```

Comment: With a simple typo, just make a comment as the question will likely be closed.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're using `row[i]` instead of `row[j]`. (For the moment, you're using the index of the first loop)

```js
const list = [['A' , 'B' , 'C', 'D'],
             ['E' , 'F' , 'G', 'H'],
             ['I' , 'J' , 'K', 'L'] ]; 

for (let i = 0; i < list.length ; i++){ 
  const row = list[i];
  console.log(`LIST #${i + 1}`);
  for (let j = 0; j < row.length ; j++){
    console.log(row[j]); /* row[j] instead of row[i] */
  }
}
```

Moreover, if you want, you can use `.map` for your array `list` insead of for loops.

```js
const list = [['A' , 'B' , 'C', 'D'],
             ['E' , 'F' , 'G', 'H'],
             ['I' , 'J' , 'K', 'L'] ];
             
list.map((list, listIndex) => {
  console.log(`LIST #${listIndex+1}`);
  console.log(list.join(' '));
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: There's no really precise question, we have to guess what is the exact question, there's so many things to say about this code sample...
So please don't blame people which are trying to answer

Comment: @Acuao And you did not see the first answer before it was edited.... lol

Comment: map() should not be used for looping if you are not going to use map() as it is intended.